# How can I copy a file and paste it to the clipboard using Java?

Tags: java

How can I copy a file and paste it to the clipboard using Java? My program can copy but it cannot paste. It gives

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   java.util.Arrays$ArrayList cannot be cast to java.io.File

My code:

```
class FileTransferable implements Transferable {
    private final File file;

    public FileTransferable(File file) {
        this.file = file;
    }

    @Override
    public DataFlavor[] getTransferDataFlavors() {
        return new DataFlavor[] { DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor };
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor flavor) {
        return DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor.equals(flavor);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getTransferData(DataFlavor flavor) throws UnsupportedFlavorException, IOException {
        final ArrayList<File> files = new ArrayList<File>();
        files.add(file);
        return files;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think the exception is being thrown by the part of the code you have included. Please check the line number of the exception and add the relevant portion of the code to your question.

Comment: Why are you returning an ArrayList? I'm not very familiar with this realm of java, but considering that the exception involves casting from an ArrayList... maybe try returning `file` directly?

Answer (score 0):

I can't detect any problem in the actual code. I guess, that the cast error occurs where you actually *receive* the content from the copy/paste operation, where you receive a file, wrapped in a list and *may* cast the list to `File`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a full example taken from the DGuitar source code were I have removed the custom or specific Details based on your comment

```
/*
 * ADropTargetListener
 * Created on 20/04/2005
 *
 *
 */

import java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable;
import java.awt.datatransfer.UnsupportedFlavorException;
import java.awt.dnd.DnDConstants;
import java.awt.dnd.DropTargetDragEvent;
import java.awt.dnd.DropTargetDropEvent;
import java.awt.dnd.DropTargetEvent;
import java.awt.dnd.DropTargetListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


/**
 * The Drop action happens in this order: 1. dragEnter =
when the mouse enters
 * the component 2. dragOver = after the mouse has entered
but has not been
 * released 3. drop = when the mouse is released
 * 
 * @author Mauricio Gracia G
 */
public class ADropTargetListener implements DropTargetListener {
    /**
     * creates a DropTargetListener 
     */
    public ADropTargetListener() {

    }

    /**
     * overrides the DROP method.
     * 
     * @see java.awt.dnd.DropTargetListener#drop(java.awt.dnd.DropTargetDropEvent)
     */
    public void drop(DropTargetDropEvent dtde) {
        Transferable transfer;

        transfer = dtde.getTransferable();

        //we must accept the transfer to process it
        dtde.acceptDrop(DnDConstants.ACTION_COPY_OR_MOVE);

        importData(transfer);
    }
    /**
     * Imports the data of the Drop action
     * @param t the transferable object
     */

    public void importData(Transferable t) {
        if (canImport(t.getTransferDataFlavors())) {
            try {
                DataFlavor[] flavors = t.getTransferDataFlavors();
                for (int i = 0; i < flavors.length; i++) {
                    //       Drop from Windows
                    if (DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor.equals(flavors[i])) {

                        Object gtd ;

                        gtd = t.getTransferData(DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor) ;
                        if (gtd instanceof List) {
                            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                            List<File> fileList = (List<File>) gtd;

                                                        //YOUR CODE here to process the list of Files

                        }

                    }
                    //       Drop from GNOME or kde
                    // delimited by \n  (\r\n) on gnome
                    // will need to remove file:// at start
                    else if (DataFlavor.stringFlavor.equals(flavors[i])) {
                        if (t.getTransferData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor)
instanceof String) {
                            String path = (String) t
                                    .getTransferData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);
                            List<File> fileList = convertStringsToFileList(path);
                            //YOUR CODE here to process the list of Files

                        }

                    }
                }
            } catch (UnsupportedFlavorException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
        }
    }
    /**
     * converts Strings in certain format to a FileList 
     * @param filestr   the list of files in a single string
     * @return          a list of files
     */

    private ArrayList<File> convertStringsToFileList(String filestr) {
        ArrayList<File> files = new ArrayList<File>();
        String[] tokenizedFiles = filestr.split("\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < tokenizedFiles.length; i++) {
            String path = tokenizedFiles[i];
            if (path.startsWith("file://")) {
                if (path.endsWith("\r")) {
                    //appears to be the case for gnome but not kde
                    path = path.substring(7);
                    path = path.replaceAll("\r", "");

                    path = path.replaceAll("%20", " ");
                } else {
                    path = path.substring(7);
                }
            }
            files.add(new File(path));

        }
        return files;
    }
    /**
     * Determine if it can import certain flavor
     * 
     * @param flavors   an array of DataFlavors
     * @return true or not depending on the flavor
     */
    public boolean canImport(DataFlavor[] flavors) {
        for (int i = 0; i < flavors.length; i++) {
            if (DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor.equals(flavors[i])) {
                return true;
            } else if (DataFlavor.stringFlavor.equals(flavors[i])) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }


    /**
     * method that is called when the drag starts or enters the window
     * @param dtde a DropTargetDragEvent
     * 
     * @see java.awt.dnd.DropTargetListener#dragEnter(java.awt.dnd.DropTargetDragEvent)
     */
    public void dragEnter(DropTargetDragEvent dtde) {
        //DEBUG
        //System.out.println("dragEnter" + ":" + dtde) ;
    }

    /**
     * a method that is called when the DRAG is OVER ??
     * 
     * @see java.awt.dnd.DropTargetListener#dragOver(java.awt.dnd.DropTargetDragEvent)
     */

    public void dragOver(DropTargetDragEvent dtde) {
        //      DEBUG
        //System.out.println("dragOver" + ":" + dtde) ;
    }

    /**
     * when the drop action is changes this method is called
     * 
     * @see java.awt.dnd.DropTargetListener#dropActionChanged(java.awt.dnd.DropTargetDragEvent)
     */
    public void dropActionChanged(DropTargetDragEvent dtde) {
        //      DEBUG
        //System.out.println("dropActionChanged" + ":" + dtde) ;
    }

    /**
     * method called when the drag exits the window
     * 
     * @see java.awt.dnd.DropTargetListener#dragExit(java.awt.dnd.DropTargetEvent)
     */
    public void dragExit(DropTargetEvent dte) {
        //      DEBUG
        //System.out.println("dragExit" + ":" + dte) ;
    }

}
```

Comment: @camickr as the answer says is an example and I have updated the code so that it only uses standar API. Look for the lines that say //YOUR CODE here to process the list of Files

Answer (score -6):

Java cannot handle specific operating system-dependent operations like interfering clipboard etc. since it is a platform-independent language. In JLS and Java API there are no methods for clipboard interference, however there are methods to handle file system operations declared in  Java API as a part of JLS (java language specification) which is implemented in most of JVM implementations.

To do such things, you should develop something in C/C++ (using Win32 API etc.) natively using JNI (Java Native Interface) or use off-the-shelf binaries and call them within your Java application.

Comment: Ah, c'mon. Clipboard operation are no problem for Java. (-1 for suggesting to it in ... c/c++ *shudder*)

Comment: Yes. http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#getSystemClipboard%28%29