# Is there a way to paste a file from the system clipboard to MS Exchange's email as attachment?

Tags: java, keyboard-shortcuts, exchange-server, clipboard, email-attachments

I am doing a project that needs to send email from MS Exchange server, but the company has a policy not to turn on smtp/pop3, so I was trying to find another way to send email with Java through Exchange, searched the net couldn't find an answer [ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31712878/how-to-send-email-with-java-using-ms-exchange-server ], then I suddenly realize Java has a robot, why don't I use the robot to simulate a user action to send an email by clicking and typing and attach files as a user would usually do, so with that in mind I was able to use Java robot to open a new email, paste in "To", "CC", "Subject", "Content" and click send, it was successful.

But the only obstacle now is how to simulate the attach file action ? I just learned that Java can copy a file to the system clipboard from this question : [Can Java system clipboard copy a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31798646/can-java-system-clipboard-copy-a-file)

The next logical question is : How do you attach this file on the system clipboard on to a new email message in MS Exchange 2013 ? I tried to use shortcuts, but none of the shortcuts has attach function :

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Keyboard-shortcuts-for-Microsoft-Outlook-2013-3E1090F6-A616-42DB-ABF5-269CA3D553EE

http://www.slipstick.com/outlook/keyboard-shortcuts-outlook/

I wonder if I can somehow paste this file on the system clipboard into the email message as attachment ?

Comment: If you are doing this as a robot did you just try to get the robot to drag the file to the email?

Comment: No, I'm trying to copy the file to clipboard first, than try to somehow paste it in as an attachment. The file can't be dragged, it's some where on the network, but I can copy it to the system clipboard.

Comment: There isn't a Java clipboard, or a 'Java system clipboard', but there is a system clipboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer :

[1] Use the method at the following question to copy the file to system clipboard : [Can Java system clipboard copy a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31798646/can-java-system-clipboard-copy-a-file)

[2] Use Java robot to click on the Outlook icon

[3] Use robot to do : Ctrl+Shift+ M  [ Create a new Message (from any Outlook folder) ]

[4] Use robot to type in "To","CC","Subject","Content" [ Use robot to type "tab" to go through them ]

[5] Use robot to do a Ctrl+V to paste the file from system clipboard to the email, it will be automatically attached to the email.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are really looking for in order to send an email is the Exchange Web Service Java API: https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-java-api

Comment: Seems awkward, I'm writing a Java Swing desktop application, and I'm not in control of the Exchange server, it seems requiring to turn on some web service to be able to use it, right ? What if the company doesn't want to turn on web service ?